# How to access socket.IO object created in a dart file from other dart files?

Tags: flutter, socket.io

I have used the following codes to initialize socket.io in my project:

**HomeScreen.dart:**

```
    import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;
    .
    .
    .
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}
.
.
.
      initSocket(){
            IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://localhost:4001', IO.OptionBuilder().setTransports(['websocket']).build());
        socket.connect();
        socket.onConnect((_) {
          print('Connected to the socket');
          socket.emit('join', {"username": "alex2020"});
        });
      }
    .
    .
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        initSocket();
      }
```

I want to emit a message to the socket server in some other dart files. Do I need to recreate `socket` in each dart file?
Is it possible to access `socket` initialized in this file (from other files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also worked with socket io. I did 2 different versions:

1. You can pass your socket object to the child Widgets.

- its easier to build from your code state now.
- It is not the best Practice, because u always have to pass the socket to every children.

2. You can build a Stream and Stream provider.

- It will take more time to build (code and learn to provide your own Stream)
- Much cleaner and better than to pass from child to child.

For 1. you can work with
`late IO.Socket socket;`and initialize it later. And pass it to your children like
`MyChildWidget(socket: socket);`

and your child Widget can you define like:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({
    required this.socket,
    super.key,
  });
  final IO.Socket socket;
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  /// Do stuff with ur socket here.
  /// with widget.socket
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}
```